# Reuse variables from cmd in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm having problems accessing environment variables I set in cmd in PowerShell.

I want to overwrite the variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE from x86 to AMD64. For this case I have a cmd script "test.cmd" that has the following content:

```
set PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
call powershell %~dp0\test.ps1
```

As you can see, I'm calling a PowerShell script called `test.ps1` in the same folder with the following content:

```
echo $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
```

Unfortunately that prints the following:

```
x86
```

I think PowerShell takes a fresh copy of the global environment variables instead of using the modified set from the cmd it was invoked from.

Is there a way to use the modified value of PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE in my PowerShell script without the use of parameters?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I run `set PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=foo` and then `call powershell ./test.ps1` in a cmd it prints `foo` correctly

Comment: You have `bash` tagged in this question - how exactly are you running all this?

Comment: If you are running the 32-bit copy of `cmd.exe` then this is expected.